# Why JFlex reject .+?(?=->)

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, jflex

I'm trying design simple language idea plugin.
I want to match below example code as 3 tokens as text before `->`, between `->` and `:`, after `:`

Ex: `First part -> Second Part: Third part`

For first part when I try regex `.+?(?=->)` at https://regex101.com/r/TDBWg0/1 it works.
But as per JFlex `.+?(?=->)` has a syntax error:

```
Error in file "Simple.flex" (line 41):  
Syntax error.
FIRST_PART=.+(?=(->))  
              ^
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error was?

Comment: May be because lookahead is not supported.

Comment: Error message added to question.

Comment: @samjay, it would be great, if you share the whole `*.flex` file

Answer (score 2):

Lexer generators like JFlex often have a different syntax and feature set than most other regex implementations, so helpers like regex101 aren't always that useful for them. Instead you should look at [the JFlex manual](https://www.jflex.de/manual.html#Grammar) to see which syntax JFlex supports.

There's two things of note there:

- The syntax for lookahead is `/regex` not `(?=regex)`
- There is no syntax for non-greedy quantifiers
- < and > need to be quoted or escaped

So `.+/"->"` would be a valid regex, but when there are multiple `->`s it will match up to the last `->`, not the first. Presumably you tried to make the `+` non-greedy specifically so that it would only match up to the first, so this is no good.

Since there are no non-greedy modifiers in JFlex, we need a different approach. If we look at the available regex features again, we'll see that there's an operator `~`, which works as follows:

> `~a` (upto)
>
> matches everything up to (and including) the first occurrence of a text matched by `a`. The expression `~a` is equivalent to `!([^]* a [^]*) a`. A traditional C-style comment is matched by `"/*" ~"*/"`.

So the regex you want is simpy `~"->"`.

Another approach, that works with virtually every regex implementation, would be to write a regex that specifically matches everything that's not a `->`, i.e. any non-`-` character or a `-` not followed by a `>`. So that'd be:

```
([^-]|-[^\>])+
```